# Every open cover of a smooth Manifold has a regular refinement

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to understand the proof of

```
Let M be a smooth manifold. Every open cover of M has a regular refinement.
```

The proof begins as follows [Lee] :

Let $X$ be an open cover of $M$, and let $\{V_j\}$  be a countable, locally finite cover of M by precompact open sets. For each $p \in M$ let $(W_p,\phi_p))$ be a coordinate chart centred at p such that:

1) $\phi_p(W_p)=B_3(0)$

2) $W_p$ is contained in one of the open sets of $X$ and

3) if $p$ in $V_j$,then $W_p \subset V_j$ as well.
(The last condition is possible because of the local finiteness of $\{V_j\}$)

...

My Problem:

As I have little knowledge of topology, In my mind the openess of $V_j$ suffices to make the last condition possible and I do not understand why the local finiteness is necessary.

Comment: The proof you're quoting does not appear in this form in either of the published editions of my smooth manifolds book. You seem to be looking at one of the pirated early drafts, which somebody posted illegally on the internet. Those are full of errors and come with no guarantees. The proof in either of the published editions should be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @JackLee I think there is no mistake in this excerpt.

Comment: @DanielValenzuela: You're correct -- this particular excerpt is not wrong, it's just not explained very clearly, which is why it confused the OP. That's why it's much better to look at the published version of the book. (Not to mention that downloading copyrighted material without permission is illegal.)

Comment: @JackLee 1) You're implying that the OP download the book in an illegal way, just because of what he typed differs from what you saw. 2) Even if so, that is not really mine or your concern, nor do I see the OP's request to teach him about if what he did is potentially illegal. 3) You still pretend as if what you're writing has something to do with this question, without mentioning that this is just pure personal advice which is completely useless for answering this question. I guess that is just not my taste.

Comment: Oh, I actually just saw that you are the author of this book, hence *it actually is your concern* in some way. Sorry for bothering you then. (that also explains why you have multiple copies of the book).

Comment: @JackLee I just went to the university library and looked into the published edition and saw that it differs to a great extend and is explained in more detail (not just on this proof). Unfortunately all the circulating books are borrowed since the beginning of the semester, and I will have to wait 1 more week till it is my turn. Thus I thought I would do no harm if I already began studying with the online version. But of course you are right!

Comment: @Falafel: You might check out your university library's website -- most recent Springer texts are available online free for users at universities that have subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3) means that you can choose each $W_p$ in a uniform way with respect to the cover. I.e. as $p$ is only contained in finitely many $V_j$, there is a nice ball around $p$ contained in *all* $V_j$, i.e. in the intersection.

Another way to say this comes basically immediately from the definition of topology: Finite intersections of open sets are open, however infinite intersections don't have to be.

An easy example would be: $\{ (-\frac 1n , \frac 1n),n\in \mathbb N\}$ forms an open cover of $(-1,1)$ however $0$ does not have an open neighborhood which is contained in all open sets, that is to say $$\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)=\{0\}.$$